# Using devtools::document to compile Rcpp code that includes foreign package

Tags: r, include, g++, devtools

I'm trying to develop an `R` `package` (named `gpuUtils`) that will import `C++` code that makes use of `RViennaCL` for `GPU` utilization.

I installed [RViennaCL](https://github.com/cdeterman/RViennaCL). Then, I followed [Hadley's guidelines for package development](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html) and [usage of C++ code](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html), and created a C++ file with these lines:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include "viennacl/ocl/backend.hpp"

using namespace Rcpp;
```

Then, when running `devtools::document` I get this error:

```
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/home/ndr/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"/home/ndr/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/home/ndr/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RViennaCL/include"   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c gpuUtils.cpp -o gpuUtils.o
In file included from /home/ndr/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RViennaCL/include/viennacl/ocl/backend.hpp:26:0,
                 from gpuUtils.cpp:3:
/home/ndr/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RViennaCL/include/viennacl/ocl/context.hpp:28:19: fatal error: CL/cl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CL/cl.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [gpuUtils.o] Error 1
```

`OpenCL` and `CUDA` are installed and I do see `CL/cl.h` in my system:

```
$ ls -1 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/CL
cl_egl.h
cl_ext.h
cl_gl_ext.h
cl_gl.h
cl.h
cl.hpp
cl_platform.h
opencl.h
```

and

```
$ ls -1 /usr/include/CL/
cl2.hpp
cl_egl.h
cl_ext.h
cl_gl_ext.h
cl_gl.h
cl.h
cl.hpp
cl_platform.h
opencl.h
```

Also, in my DESCRIPTION file I have these lines:

```
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RViennaCL (>= 1.7.1.7)
Imports: Rcpp
```

I guess that either `-I/usr/include/` or `-I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/` have to be included in my `g++` call, but I'm not sure how to get `Rstudio` to do that.

Any idea?

Comment: From `RViennaCL`'s [GitHub](https://github.com/cdeterman/RViennaCL): "It can be used via the LinkingTo: field in the DESCRIPTION field of an R package --- and the R package infrastructure tools will then know how to set include flags correctly on all architectures supported by R." Have you tried adding RViennaCL to the Linking to field?

Comment: Also see "Importing C++ code" in the [Compiled code chapter](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#clang) of Hadley Wickham's R Packages book

Comment: Thanks for the comment @duckmayr. I updated my post to show that RViennaCL does appear in my DESCRIPTION file. In Hadley's section on "Importing C++ code" I don't think it refers to other C++ libraries but rather R packages that use C++. In my case RViennaCL is using CL (including CL/cl.h from context.hpp) but the compiler cannot find CL in the path. So my question is how to add it to the path so it will. BTW, I'm running this on a linux system and both /usr/include/ and /usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/ are exported to PATH)

Comment: Will this package be distributed, or only for your own use?

Comment: Probably only for my own use

Comment: Then you may try just adding -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include/ to PKG_CPPFLAGS in your Makevars file in the src directory.